# Can I use AMP to accept payments?

Tags: amp-html

What are the different ways of accepting payments with AMP? Are there restrictions on which payment processors I can use? And if not, is there anything specific to AMP that I need to do to set-up?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the official [Payments in AMP](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/payments_in_amp/):

> Via [amp-iframe](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/) and
>   the allowpaymentrequest attribute, AMP pages can support requesting
>   payment information directly from the browser. The PaymentRequest API
>   is an open W3C spec with support from most major browsers. This
>   example won't go into detail on the API, but you can get more
>   information in this deep dive article.